# Looping to do cloud mask for several raster files in R

Tags: raster, r, loop

I have over 200 land surface temp (LST) rasters and I want to mask each LST raster using the corresponding cloud Mask raster. The working directory has two folders one for LST and one for cloud Mask. I have tried the following code but did not work.
Is there a way to loop the mask code?

Here is my code:

```
setwd("D:/22/test")

files = list.files("./Cloud_Mask/")
files

for(f in files){
  CM = raster(file.path("Cloud_Mask",f))
  LST0 = raster(file.path("LST",f))
  out= mask(LST0, CM, inverse=FALSE,maskvalue=1)
  
  writeRaster(out, file.path("LST_Masked",f)) # save the result of each LST to one empty folder
}

examples of names of rasters:
Cloud Mask rasters:
ECO2CLD.001_SDS_CloudMask_doy2018216102745_aid0001.tif
ECO2CLD.001_SDS_CloudMask_doy2018217192347_aid0001.tif
ECO2CLD.001_SDS_CloudMask_doy2018219092910_aid0001.tif

LST rasters:
ECO2LSTE.001_SDS_LST_doy2018216102745_aid0001.tif
ECO2LSTE.001_SDS_LST_doy2018217192347_aid0001.tif
ECO2LSTE.001_SDS_LST_doy2018219092910_aid0001.tif
```

Comment: When you say something "did not work" you should explain how it didn't work - what went wrong compared to what you expected. Did you get error messages? Did you silently get no output? Error messages should help you work out where you are going wrong and if you tell us what errors you got then we can help you understand them along with giving you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your mask files are different names than the LST files but, you are using the cloud mask file names. I would highly recommend moving to terra as, it is the developers replacement for raster. Note, you can avoid file.path in you loop by returning the full paths in list.files.

```
( cm.files <- list.files(file.path(getwd(), 
    "Cloud_Mask"), "tif$", full.names=TRUE) )

( lst.files <- list.files(file.path(getwd(), "LST"), 
    "tif$", full.names=TRUE) )

for(f in 1:length(lst.files)){
  CM <- terra::rast(cm.files[f])
  LST0 <- terra::rast(lst.files[f])
  out <- mask(LST0, CM, inverse=FALSE,maskvalue=1)
  writeRaster(out, file.path(getwd(), "LST_Masked", 
              basename(lst.files[f])) 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. I just changed "base.name" to "basename".

Comment: Sorry, I was answering on my phone and accidentally typed base.name. Hopefully it did not cause any inconvenience.

Comment: Not at all, I really appreciate your assistant.